# How can i also get count of records between 2 dates in grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm

i have a query below i want the count between 2 dates within the same gorm query

```
    def view = StackHash.createCriteria().list(params) {
        if(params?.process){
            eq("process",params.process)
            between("lastDateOfOccurence", fromDate, upToDate)
        }
        order("occurrence", "desc")
    }

    [
        title              : title,
        filter             : CommonService.makeFilterParams(params),
        subtitle           : subtitle,
        view               : view,
        reportInstanceTotal: StackHash.count() ///this is getting total number of records in the database irrespective of dates
    ]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `totalCount` attribute of the results if you want to know the total number of records that match your criteria:

```
def view = StackHash.createCriteria().list(params) {
        if(params?.process){
            eq("process",params.process)
            between("lastDateOfOccurence", fromDate, upToDate)
        }
        order("occurrence", "desc")
    }

    [
        title              : title,
        filter             : CommonService.makeFilterParams(params),
        subtitle           : subtitle,
        view               : view,
        reportInstanceTotal: view.totalCount
    ]
```

Note that `view.totalCount` is not necessarily the same as `view.size()`.  `.size()` will tell you how many records are in the result set where `.totalCount` will tell you how many records match the search criteria.  Those numbers could be different.  For example, if there are 1,000 records in your database, 500 of the records match your criteria and `params` contains something like `[max: 10, offset: 0]` then `.size()` would be 10 but `.totalCount` would be 500.

I hope that helps.